# Question about tensor product of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I've come to think about this problem when reading a proof in *Commutative Algebra* by *N. Bourbaki*. Say, let $R$ be a commutative ring, given 3 $R-$modules $A$, $B$, $C$, and the $R$-homomorphism $f:B \to C$. Is the following equivalent?

1. $f: B \to C$  is an isomorphism.
2. $1_A \otimes f: A \otimes B \to A \otimes C$  is an isomorphism.

I think they are equivalent, as I see the author using this fact in the proof. $1 \Rightarrow 2$ is straight-forward. But I fail to see how to prove: $2 \Rightarrow 1$. Is it correct? Any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you guys very much,

And have a good day,

Comment: doesn't this follow from functoriality of tensor product? note that a functor preserves isomorphisms.

Comment: Hi, I know that the functor $1_A \otimes -$ preserves isomorphism. However, I'm asking the other way round.

Comment: sorry, i missed that. the implication $2\implies 1$ does not hold. Take for instance $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,$C=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Then $A\otimes B=A\otimes C=0$, but $B$ and $C$ are not isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: On the other hand, $2 \implies 1$ will hold if $A$ is a faithfully flat $R$-module (e.g. a free $R$-module)

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I misread the text, and I can't believe I made such a silly mistake. :( I'll delete the topic after some minutes. :(

Comment: What is wrong with this question that would motivate you to delete it? Just because a question has an easy answer does not mean it won't be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Even easier: Take $A=0$ to see that $2$ does not imply $1$.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered in comments:

> The implication $2\implies 1$ does not hold. Take for instance $\mathbb{Z}$-modules $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $C=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Then $A\otimes B=A\otimes C=0$, but $B$ and $C$ are not isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. –  adrido Jan 25 at 8:04

and

> Even easier: Take $A=0$ to see that 2 does not imply 1. –  Julian Kuelshammer Jan 25 at 9:17

while

> On the other hand, $2\implies 1$ will hold if $A$ is a faithfully flat $R$-module (e.g. a free $R$-module). –  zcn Jan 25 at 8:06